# Zend_Session::rememberMe() conundrum: Where to put it if there are plugins that already use sessions?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

Most of my urls have a language component to them that helps me determine what language to show content in but some other don't. The site remembers the user's language by means of a cookie. This is all handled in a custom plugin `Application_Plugin_Locale` which upon construction detects the language or uses the one in the existing session.

Problem: This plugin obviously runs before any actions as most of them are language dependent. This prevents me from using Zend_Session::rememberMe() as this needs to happen before a session is started. Also, while showing the login form I check weather a login has already happened with Zend_Auth (which also starts my session before I want to).

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the application structure to avoid this and having every URL contain the language so that I wouldn't need to detect it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use your application.ini (ZF 1.8+)

```
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
```

Comment: do you know when does that get executed?